# Time Complexity of an algorithm : How to decide which algorithm after calculated the time

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Today i'm come across with the blog in msdn and i noticed how to calculate the time complexity of an algorithm. I perfectly understand how to calculate the time complexity of an algorithm but in the last the author mentioned the below lines

> Adding everything up I get
>
> (N+4)+(5N+2)+(4N+2) = 10N+8
>
> So the asymptotic time complexity for the above code is O(N), which
>   means that the above algorithm is a liner time complexity algorithm.

So how come the author is said it's based on the liner time complexity algorithm. The link for the blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nmallick/archive/2010/03/30/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-for-a-given-algorithm.aspx.

Comment: if you feel that some answer respond to your question please tag it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He said that because 10N + 8 is a linear equation. If you plot that equation you get a straight line. Try typing `10 * x + 8` on this website ([function graphs](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/)) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The author just based on his experience in choosing most appropriate . You should know, that counting algorithm complexity almost always means to find a **Big-Oh** function, which, in turn, is just an **upper bound** to given function (**10N+8** in your case).

There is only a few well-known complexity types: *linear* complexity, *quadratic* complexity, [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). So, the final step of counting a time complexity consists of choosing what is the less complex type (i mean, *linear* is less complex than a *quadratic*, and *quadratic* is less complex that *exponential*, and so on) can be used for the given function, which correctly describe its complexity.

In your case, O(n) and O(n^2) and even O(2^n) are the **right answers** indeed. But the less complex function, which suits perfectly in [Big-Oh notation definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is **O(n)**, which is an answer here.

Here is a [real good article](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs202.f98/readings/asymptotic/asymptotic.html), fully explained **Big-Oh notation**.

Answer (score 0):

Ascending order of time complexities(the common one)

```
O(1) - Constant
O(log n) - logarithmic
O(n) - linear
O(n log n) - loglinear
O(n^2) - quadratic
```

Note: N increases without bounds

Answer (score 0):

For complexity theory you definitely should read some background theory. It's usually about asymptotic complexity, which is why you can drop the smaller parts, and only keep the complexity class.

The key idea is that the difference between `N` and `N+5` becomes neglibile once `N` is really big.

For more details, start reading here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 0):

A very pragmatic rule is:

**when the complexity of an algorithm si represented by a poly** like `A*n^2+B*n+C` **then the order of complexity**  ( that is to say the O(something) ) **is equal to the highest order of the variable n**.

In the `A*n^2+B*n+C` poly the order is O(n^2).

Like josnidhin explained, if the poly has

- order 1  (i.e. n)- it is called linear
- order 2  (i.e. n^2) - it is called quadratic
- ... and so on.